# Constructing Implementation of scalaz.Equal[Foo]

Tags: implicit, scalaz

Given the following class:

```
scala> class Foo(x: Int) { def getX = x }
defined class Foo
```

I created an `implicit Equal[Foo]` to be able to use `===`.

```
scala> implicit val FooEq: Equal[Foo] = Equal.equal(_.getX == _.getX)
FooEq: scalaz.Equal[Foo] = scalaz.Equal$$anon$7@6a246ad
```

It works.

```
scala> new Foo(10) === new Foo(10)
res2: Boolean = true

scala> new Foo(10) === new Foo(4545)
res3: Boolean = false
```

But, I'm confused by how the the `FooEq` gets created.

What's going on in `Equal.equal(_.getX == _.getX)`? I'm not sure how that statement returns an `Equal[Foo]`.

Comment: I guess I got down votes since I foolishly did not read the return type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type signature of `Equal.equal` is `def equal[A](f: (A, A) => Boolean): Equal[A]`. So you're passing a method that takes two `Foo`s and gives back a `Boolean` to `equals` which gives back an instance of `Equal[Foo]`. That's whats going on and that's how the statement returns and `Equal[Foo]`.

[Here's some code that you've written using similar syntax.](https://github.com/kevinmeredith/lisp_interpretter/blob/master/src%2Fmain%2Fscala%2Fnet%2Fparser%2FLispParser.scala#L6-L8)